# joining two pics seamlessly in a div

Tags: html, css

I have two pics **pic1.png (100px x 20px**) and **pic2.png (100px x 380px**) which each are inside a link and **should look like one pic of 100px x 400 px**. Unfortunally (at least in Firefox and IE) as a result there is a **visible gap** of several px between these two pics.

**Website-Source** (please excuse that I put it all into one line - but I did not want to possibly falsify the exact code by formatting):

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;height:400px;max-height:400px"><a href="someurl"><img alt="somealt" title="sometitle" src="pic1.png"></a><a href="someurl"><img alt="somealt" title="sometitle" src="pic2.png"></a></div>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong in the above Source and how I could fix it?

Comment: Could you possibly inspect the output with Firebug or a similar tool and see if there's any margin, padding or border involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are being rendered one below the other, as if they were text, *in different lines*. Thus, the `line-height` CSS property is causing a visible space within them, in the same way that you expect some spacing between lines of text.

You can solve this by adding `line-height: 0;` to the style of the div.

See an example: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/h56r823b/)

Comment: Also thanks to @caramba who posted an answer (`* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 0;
}
.wrap {
    display:inline-block;width:100px;height:400px;max-height:400px
}`)  in the beginning which was not the exact solution I seeked but brought me to the answer abl has posted above

Answer (score 0):

you should add border="0" attribute to the images, the fact that the browsers add a border of 1 or 2 pixels to the images that are inside an anchor  tag and use the default "link" styling, probably you are getting the space between the images.

```
<a href="someurl"><img alt="somealt" title="sometitle" src="pic1.png" border="0"></a>
```

or in CSS file that you're including, this will make that any image inside an anchor tag has no border:

```
a img { border: 0; }
```

Comment: do you have the page in a site where we can check what's going on? probably in another css file you have a border, or margin, or padding set for all elements, i usually check which css properties are being applied and inherited with google chrome dev tools (right click, inspect element), or firebug on firefox. there you can apply properties 'on the fly' and test without reloading the page until you're satisfiied and pass all of this to the css file.

Comment: It was initially in a site with css, but I also tested it standalone both with the same result - it came out that the solution was to add `line-height: 0` to the style of the div.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/njwx47tg/ 
Why don't you use `float:left`? to the `a` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;height:400px;max-height:400px;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;"><a href="someurl"><img alt="somealt" title="sometitle" src="pic1.png"></a><a href="someurl"><img alt="somealt" title="sometitle" src="pic2.png"></a></div>
```

Add:

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
```